# Struts2 Tiles - how to implement?

Tags: java, struts2

I am just experimenting with struts2 tiles. I don't know how to implement it. Can anyone give any link for simple example of using strus2 tiles ? What is the basic requirement for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tiles project itself has a [tutorial for first-time Tiles users](http://tiles.apache.org/tutorial/index.html) and the Struts plugin for Tiles is explained [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.9/docs/tiles-plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

**I know i am answering after long time this may help some one in future,**

1. let me give you the maven dependency

   ```
                       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
       <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.6</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   This is the jar it will download or you need:
   commons.logging-api-1.1.jar,b)struts2-tiles-plugin-2.1.6.jarc)tiles-api-2.0.6.jard)tiles-core-2.0.6.jare)tiles-jsp-2.0.6.jar

Note : if you get the following error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.

add this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

or add this jar :
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar

after having all in Java Build path
Follow this link to [Happy Learning](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_tiles.htm)